# How do you specify SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount when using AddIdentityExpressAdminUiConfiguration() instead of AddDefaultIdentity()?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm using `services.AddIdentityExpressAdminUiConfiguration()` from the IdentityExpress package. How do I specify `SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount`?

Normally this would be accomplished in the `services.AddDefaultIdentity()` call, but since `AddIdentityExpressAdminUiConfiguration()` adds the identity, I would end up with an exception if I did that.

Adding the following to ConfigureServices() does not work:
 `services.Configure<SignInOptions>(x => x.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).` because `UserManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount` is always false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I accomplished this by adding the following to `Configure()`:

`app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Value.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;`

This will also work for setting the password strength attributes, etc.

Attempting to set this inside `ConfigureServices()` didn't work. I suspect it's being overriden by the logic inside `AddIdentityExpressAdminUiConfiguration()`

Comment: I don't even use Express Identity and this solved my problem as well, thank you!